# Tkinter doesn't recognize my variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a counter in Tkinter though for some reason python does not recognise my variable and print's from my else statement.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

a = random.randrange(1,10)
b = random.randrange(1,10)
c = random.randrange(1,10)
d = random.randrange(1,10)
print a, b, c, d

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.Input = Entry(frame)
        self.Input.pack()

        self.display = Label(frame, text='')
        self.display.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.confirm = Button(frame, text='confirm', command=self.confirm)
        self.confirm.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def confirm(self):
        enter = self.Input.get()
        abc = 0

        if enter == a:
            abc += 1
            self.display['text'] = abc
            print('a')

        elif enter == b:
            abc += 2
            self.display['text'] = abc
            print('b')

        elif enter == c:
            abc += 3
            self.display['text'] = abc
            print('c')

        elif enter == d:
            abc += 4
            self.display['text'] = abc
            print('d')

        else:
            print('invalid character')



root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't recognize my variable?" Precisely, what is the error message you see? If your program output is incorrect, what is it, and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

This line, I suppose, returns a `str`, for example, `'7'`:

```
enter = self.Input.get()
```

This line returns an `int`, for example, `7`:

```
a = random.randrange(1,10)
```

Note that `7 != '7'`.

You might try changing this line:

```
enter = int(self.Input.get())
```

or the lines like this one:

```
if enter == str(a):
```

Comment: Thank you this helped solve my problem thought another question is how do make the counter update itself for example, every time i press the confirm button the number increases by 1 so that it may eventually become 10 by pressing the button 10 times and once again thank you very much

Comment: In `App.__init__()`, add this line: `self.counter = 0`. In `App.confirm()`, add this line: `self.counter += 1`.